# Autoupdating Android app without user click

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-search

Can I design my app so it closes everyday to check for updates and if there are any, it will update and then restart.? If not then just restart and check again next day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not usually. However, there are options if this is for a kiosk mode experience. You should read about [Google Play managed devices for enterprises](https://developer.android.com/distribute/google-play/work.html) which I think allows a device admin to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Your app should never turn off by itself.
This is basic User Experience.

What happens if the user is doing something at the time your app kill itself ? It would look like a crash or a poor quality of the app.

You should check if your version is the newest one, if not, you can play a pop up once to tell the user, but you should not prevent the user from using your app even if it's old

Comment: yes i understand the basic user experience but this app is designed for old people who may not be able to update it themselves and the we need the app running as well in the foreground as they may not be able to navigate back to it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best solution for my problem is using a 3rd party MDM and then push a silent install on the device. But this will be possible only in certain devices which are rooted or a few other ones.